# WP7: Is it possible to navigate to a page in the backstack instead of creating a new instance of that page?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a Windows Phone 7.1 application in which I got three pages, and on each page I got 3 buttons: first one leading to page no. 1, second leading to page no. 2 and third leading to page no. 3.

The thing is that if I go to page 1 then page 2 - and then if I click on the first button to navigate to the first page a new instance of that page will be created. Instead of creating a new instance I would like to navigate to the existing instance of the page from the back stack.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to navigate backwards manually by triggering a go back (mostly equivalent to the user pressing the back button):

`NavigationService.GoBack();`

This will utilise the back stack as maintained by the OS.  It will pop page 2 and re-instate page 1.  Note that **you cannot choose** what page to go back to, it goes backwards one page if there is a page to back onto.  So for example triggering a backwards navigation from page 3 will get you to page 2, you cannot pick page 1.

Alternatively, but not advised, you can in 7.1 pop pages off the back stack:

`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();`

You could then manually navigate to the page.  But seriously, try not to do that as it breaks user expectations, unless you manage page backing yourself.

Comment: I see. I knew about the GoBack() method but I was looking for a way to choose which page to go back to. Removing them from the backstack and keeping only one instance of a page in it at once is definitely a solution. Why I want to do this: if you'd use an application which works as the one I described above for let's say 5 minutes and you would browse between the pages like 20 times, then you would need to hit back 20 times in order to close that app.

Comment: No you wouldn't, if when you navigate between the pages you do so using `GoBack` where appropriate, it pops the page you come from off the stack.  In your case, if done properly, your stack should only ever be 2 pages big at most.  Also, buttons to go between pages is not in line with the user expectations.  If a user is on page 2 and wants to get to page 1, chances are ***extremely*** good that they will use the back button.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Sorry for rising dead threads, but i have a question about `But seriously, try not to do that as it breaks user expectations, unless you manage page backing yourself.` In my scenario, i have pages: MainMenu (with products) -> Settings -> ListOfStores -> StoreDetails (here user can confirm selected store, this triggers update of the MainMenu). How can i return to the main page after the store selection in "user expected" manner without using nonlinearnavigationservice?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I mean, of course, i can return user to the previous page every time, but that would make user to do several extra actions every time.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko If you are managing the back state yourself, then that approach will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You would be better suited using a framework such as MVVM to control your data instead of relying on specific instances of a page, but still remembering where the user was up to on that page.

MVVMLight is a good choice - http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/

You would then just need to control your navigation better within the app deciding how the app should flow instead of relying on the backstack.  Back is just meant to go back based on the users choice not a flow direction of your app (don't depend on it).

Features such as removing back entries in mango are a workarround to solve old issues where the user navigates home and you want to prevent returning to an invalid point in the app flow.

Comment: Data control is not an issue, and I'm already using MVVM. I'm just worried that this might affect performance.

Answer (score 1):

you can do `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri..` In combination with nonlinearnavigationservice. this will do the back.back.back for you if you have alread been on that page. http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7